# How do I delete user in Active Directory through Powershell?

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have to delete users from my AD through Powershell. Powershell has to ask me who I want to delete, once I type in the username it should delete the account. Also when Powershell succesfully deleted the account or it should give me a message.

I'm kind of noob at this, but here is my code:

```
    function aduser-remove($userremove){
    Remove-ADUser -Identity $delete 
        if ($delete -eq $userremove){
            return $true
        }
        else {
            return $false
        }
}

$delete = Read-host "Which user do you want to delete? (Type in username)." 
aduser-remove $delete

    if ($userremove -eq $true){
        Write-Host $delete "deleted succesfully!" -ForegroundColor Green
    } 
    elseif ($userremove -eq $false){
        Write-Host "An error occured by deleting" $delete -ForegroundColor Red
    }
    else {
        Write-Host $delete "does not exist." -ForegroundColor DarkGray
    }
```

The result here is that Powershell does ask if I want to delete the account and it works. But Powershell keeps giving me the else message instead of the if message. Deleting the account was succesfull.

I have no idea what to now or if I'm missing something (I bet I am otherwise it would work).

I hope you guys can help me!

Comment: Your function `aduser-remove` has no knowledge of variable `$delete`. **Inside** that function you need to use `$userremove`. **Outside** the function, the script knows nothing of variable `$userremove`.. Also, since `Remove-ADUser` returns no output, you need to do the actual removal inside a `try/catch` block to be able to return either $true or $false. Removing a user is not something to do lightly. At least, while testing your code, add the `-WhatIf` switch to the command.

Comment: Do you mind making an example? I can't really picture this. I've been trying for days and I just don't seem to get it.

Comment: This is what Powershell gives me after running the code:

`PS C:\Users\Administrator> C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Powershell\ImportUsers\DeleteUserAD.ps1
Which user do you want to delete? (Type in username).: WesleyLang000
True
WesleyLang000 does not exist.`

Comment: @Emnasia - is there a reason you are not using the `try/catch` structure instead of the amazingly awkward code you have posted? take a look at >>> `Get-Help about_Try_Catch_Finally` <<<

Comment: Well, this is how we learned it. How would you recommend using the `try/catch`? They told us that we have to use it to see if there are errors. Like: `try { 
    if ($userremove -eq $true){
        Write-Host $delete "deleted succesfully!" -ForegroundColor Green
    } 
} catch {
    Write-Host "There is something wrong with your code." -ForegroundColor Yellow
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, your code uses variables in places where they do not exist.

Also, I would recommend trying to find the user first and if you do, try and remove it inside a `try/catch` block, as `Remove-ADUser` creates no output.

Below a rewrite of your code. Please note that I have changed the name of the function to comply with the `Verb-Noun` naming convention in PowerShell.

```
function Remove-User ([string]$userremove) {
    # test if we can find a user with that SamAccountName
    $user = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$userremove'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($user) {
        try {
            $user | Remove-ADUser -ErrorAction Stop -WhatIf
            return $true
        }
        catch {
            return $false
        }
    }
    # if we get here, the user does not exist; returns $null
}

$delete = Read-host "Which user do you want to delete? (Type in username)."

# call your function and capture the result
$result = Remove-User $delete

if ($result -eq $true){
    Write-Host "User $delete deleted succesfully!" -ForegroundColor Green
} 
elseif ($result -eq $false){
    Write-Host "An error occured while deleting user $delete" -ForegroundColor Red
}
else {
    Write-Host "$delete does not exist." -ForegroundColor DarkGray
}
```

Note also that I have put in the `-WhatIf` switch. This switch ensures you will only get a message of what *would* happen. No user is actually deleted. Once you are satisfied the code does what you want, remove the `-WhatIf` switch.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

If you have rsat installed https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520

remove-aduser https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/remove-aduser?view=win10-ps